# bcmwl-kernel-source not installing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, apt, broadcom

Ok, so this is a follow up to my last post. So Pilot6 told me to connect my phone to my computer and turn on personal hotspot. Then I booted up to Ubuntu 20.04 to install the drivers by doing:

`sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`

But it didn't work, because it didn't have dkms, libc6-dev and linux-libc-dev. So I tried to install those three packages and it still didn't work and it outputted an error saying:

`E: Package (every package i mentioned) has no installation candidate.`

So what should I do now?

Edit: Alright so I did a little bit of researching and found that the error means that I need to install a ppa.

Comment: Did you update your software lists so your box knows what i can download (ie. `sudo apt update`)  Where there error messages or clues during that first step?

Comment: Yes I did update it.

Comment: The package is there (`libc6-dev | 2.31-0ubuntu9     | focal            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`) so I'd re-run the `sudo apt update` & watch there to ensure messages are as they should be (nothing missing, no warnings, no errors etc)

Comment: Yes the `libc6-dev` package is there but it is not installing... That's a bit weird.

Comment: A `rmadison bcmwl-kernel-source` tells me it's in *restricted*, so that will be need to be enabled (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)    We need to see errors & messages in order to help you with them.

Comment: Ok so I will try that to see if it works. (Plus I need my phone)